# How can I fix cout() function?

Tags: visual-c++

I've started today lerning c++ classes and I've written a little program. Here there isn't any error of the debugger of visual studio, but the function cout isn't working. Please help me as soon as you can.

This is main.cpp

```
#include "Books.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
Books::Books(char t[], float pr, long int is) {
    strcpy_s(title, t);
    prize = pr;
    isbn = is;
}
char* Books::get_title() {
    return title;
}
float Books::get_prize() {
    return prize;
}
int main() {
    char parola[] = "bella";
    Books book1(parola, 3.75, 9000);
    cout << book1.get_prize();
    return 0;
}
```

This is Books.h

```
#ifndef BOOKS
#define BOOKS
class Books {
public:
        Books();
    Books(char t [], float pr, long int is);
    char* get_title();
    float get_prize();
private:
    char title[50];
    float prize;
    long int isbn;
};
#endif // !Books
```

Comment: What part of this isn't working? What is the behavior you see? What do you expect?

Comment: When I run the program it isn't printing on the screen and the terminal isn't opening

Comment: Once I delete the default constructor you didn't provide your program works fine for me. I copy/pasted your code, compiled, and pressed ctrl-f5 to run it. You'll have to be more specific about what you're doing because the problem seems to be in your process not the code.

Comment: To run the code with visual studio I only press f7 and it sais >Demo.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\programmi c++\Demo\Debug\Demo.exe without running the terminal

Comment: Assuming default key bindings, `F7` only builds the project, it doesn't run it.

Comment: What I have to do so?

Comment: I tried to press ctrl + f5, but the terminal open and close very fast

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the SUBSYTEM to CONSOLE .
To do that, follow the below steps.

1. Open the project properties window.
2. Select the configuration and platform in which you are running the program.
3. Navigate to `Configuration Properties -> Linker -> System`. There in the field 
   `SubSystem` use the drop-down to select `Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)` and apply the change.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, now my program is running very fust

Comment: @GiovanniSpallanzani Are you using F5(Start Debugging) or Ctrl + F5(Start without Debugging)?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of visual studio you are using, the problem you mentioned in the comments that the terminal quickly opens and closes without showing you the results, occurs most of the times. I would recommend from my experience that in the main function, just before `return 0;`, add a new line and type: `system("pause");` just as I have written. This will hopefully stop the terminal from quickly shutting down. Also, it is good programming practice to always include the class file after the preprocessing directive `#include <iostream>`. I hope this helped solve your issue! :-)